# Retrieving the connection string for a Mssql database running inside a container

Tags: python, docker, sqlalchemy, docker-desktop, azure-data-studio

I'm writing a local python script that queries an MSSQL database that runs locally and having difficulties connecting to the database. The database runs inside a docker container since I'm using a mac (i5).
I'm not sure what is the correct format for the connection string required to create the engine using sqlalchemy.
I use Azure Data Studio to query the database directly. How can I check for the connection string  from the docker desktop app or the Azure Data studio app?

I ran the following code:

```
def generate_engine(path_to_yml):
    # Load credentials from the .yml file
    credentials_file_path = path_to_yml
    credentials = load_credentials(credentials_file_path)

    if credentials:
        server = credentials['server']
        port = credentials['port']
        database = credentials['database']
        username = credentials['username']
        password = credentials['password']

        # Construct the connection string
        connection_string = f'mssql+pyodbc://{username}:{password}@{server}:{port}/{database}?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server'

        # Create the engine
        engine = create_engine(connection_string)  # Set echo=True for debugging

        # Test the connection
        try:
            connection = engine.connect()
            print("Connection successful!")
            connection.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Connection error:", e)
```

and got the following error:
`Connection error: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest" requested by the login. The login failed. (4060) (SQLDriverConnect)')` 
This is my yaml file:

```
server: localhost
port: 1433
database: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
username: sa
password: #mypassword
```

I'm not sure i put the correct string in the database field in the yaml file and in the end of the connection field.

[image: connection pane in Azure data studio]

[image: database details from the docker desktop app]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have got same error when I tried to connect MSSQL database:

[image]

There is no direct way to get connection string in Azure data studio . You can find the connection string of MSSQL server from [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).

As per [this](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-odbc-driver-17-for-sql-server/) Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server Connection String is as follows:

```
Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;UID=myUsername;PWD=myPassword;
```

I have used the connection string as above format and tried to connect SQL database with below code:

```
import urllib.parse
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

server = '<serverName>'
database = '<databaseName>'
user = '<userName>'
password = '<password>'
driver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
conn = f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={user};PWD={password};'
conn_str = urllib.parse.quote_plus(conn)

engine = create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={conn_str}', fast_executemany=True)

with engine.connect() as connection:
    result = connection.execute("SELECT * from Student")
    for row in result:
        print(row)
```

It connected successfully and executed the query successfully:

[image]

Comment: Hi Bhavani, when I am adding conn_str = urllib.parse.quote_plus(conn) for getting the required connection string, my pytest framework based unit tests are not getting discovered, any idea on that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with local settings file, this may help -

```
import urllib
import utilities.utilities as utilities
from sqlalchemy import create_engine,  text
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


SQLConnectionString = os.environ.get("AzureSQLConnectionString")
SQLConnectionString = urllib.parse.quote_plus(SQLConnectionString) 
SQLConnectionString = "mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % 
SQLConnectionString
engine = create_engine(SQLConnectionString)

# Create a session
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
```